# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. from scripts/background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i am doing a chrome extension project with manifest v3.

I tried to follow different tutorial/similar questions asked in over the web but it didnt able to solve the error.

Currently, the background.js is able sendmessage to content.js as intented. But I still wish to solve the error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Context:

```
scripts/background.js
```

Stack Trace

```
scripts/background.js:0 (anonymous function)
```

My code:
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "YT Extension",
  "description": "Youtube extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assert/icons/icon16.jpeg",
    "32": "assert/icons/icon32.jpeg",
    "48": "assert/icons/icon48.jpeg",
    "128": "assert/icons/icon128.jpeg"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "./scripts/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "js": ["./scripts/contentScript.js"]
  } ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

scripts/background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    console.log("background.js running...")

    if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/watch")) {
      console.log("Sending message: VIDEO")
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        type: "VIDEO",
      });
    }

    else if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/")) {
      console.log("Sending message: MAIN")
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        type: "MAIN",
      });
    }

    else {
      console.log("Sending message: NOT SUPPORTED")
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        type: "NOT SUPPORTED",
      });
    }

  }
}
)
```

scripts/contentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
    const { type } = obj;
    console.log("content.js running...")

    if (type === "VIDEO") {
        console.log("Received message: VIDEO")
    }
    else if (type === "MAIN") {
        console.log("Select video")
    }
    else if (type === "NOT SUPPORTED") {
        console.log("Website not supported")
    }
}
);
```

Comment: 1) A tab may be updated when it doesn't yet run a content script, which is why you see the error. You can add `.catch(()=>{})` to each sendMessage to suppress the error. 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. 3) See also [an alternatve solution](/a/34100952) for youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension is working as intended, the error you have is occured when a message is sent to a tab where no listener is set up (probably `chrome://extension`) because of security reason.

So, you must identify the tab generating this error and add the logic as follow :

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        console.log("background.js running...");

        if (!tab.url.startsWith("chrome://")) {
            //...
        }
    }
});
```